Change Home Screen Wallpaper Using ADB
How can I change the Home Screen wallpaper via ADB?
I know this question has been asked before, but none of the answers I read provided a way to instruct the phone to set only the Home Screen wallpaper. The Lock Screen wallpaper should remain unchanged.
For example, the following command works fine, but immediately after I send it to my Xiaomi phone, I get a popup window asking me which wallpaper to change: Home Screen, Lock Screen, or both.
adb shell am start \
    -a android.intent.action.ATTACH_DATA \
    -c android.intent.category.DEFAULT \
    -d file:///path/to/my/image/on/device.jpg \
    -t 'image/*' \
    -e mimeType 'image/*'

I'm looking for a way to change the Home Screen wallpaper automatically, without any manual intervention.

Related: Change wallpaper via ADB/terminal (reference to "this question has been asked before")
